# Increase the number of document tabs displayed in Geany

Tags: display, browser-tabs, geany

I'm working on a project with about 20 files. Is there a way I can increase the number of document tabs displayed, rather than having to click the arrow to scroll along?

(Perhaps show two layers of tabs?)

Answer (score 0):

You can move the tabs to one of the sides and then you are limited based on font size and screen dimensions. You could also decrease the font size of window elements and leave the tabs where they are.

Source: *[Tab positions](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#tab-positions)*